# Is there a way to program intent and is it possible to call different models on different steps in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm currently working on building a chatbot and I saw the Dialogflow tool that can provides a lot of help in this topic, so my question if it's usable to have multiple contexts at once and also to be able to call my NLP model (stored in an API)  many times? Or do I have to build my own platform for that since  Dialogflow can't be call multiple webhooks at once?

#### Example:

I have a model to classify the initial intent,
I have a regression model to do something else if the intent is XXX.

Comment: Note that I've removed the portion of your question "if you can provide me any other alternatives for Dialogflow (some OpenSource or paying ones)" since it isn't related to the first part of your question, and isn't allowed on StackOverflow since it seeks opinions. If you can phrase it in a way to not solicit opinions, you should ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remember that an Intent represents *what the user says or does* and not how you react to that.

Within that, yes, it is perfectly feasible to have multiple Contexts active at once. The lifespan of a Context determines how many rounds of the conversation it will be active for. **All** of the Input Contexts for an Intent must be active for that Intent to be *considered* for matching.

While Dialogflow only lets you register one webhook for all of the Intents, it provides information to that webhook about which Intent was triggered (along with which Contexts are active, parameter values, etc). Based on that, or any other information you wish, you can choose which code or handler to execute. In this way, you can certainly make multiple calls to other APIs if that makes sense - as long as you return within the timeout period (5-7 seconds).

Comment: Thank you sir for your response It's very clear , I just wanna know if you have any OpenSources alternatives for dialogFlow that can also provide a manual entry (for example when the AI misunderstand a query)

Comment: If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with other NLU/NLP tools to be able to offer other suggestions. You may wish to open another question with appropriate tags. However, be careful, since questions that seek opinions are generally discouraged on StackOverflow.